# Too many command line arguments. Did you mean to use -chdir?

Tags: terraform

I just run this line terraform init to initialize my terraform but it's always show this error

Folder structure

```
[ROOT]/terraform/main.tf
[ROOT]/src/lambda_code.py
[ROOT]/terraform/lambda.tf
```

Command

```
terraform init -input=false -backend=false ./terraform
terraform init validate ./terraform
```

Error:

> Too many command line arguments. Did you mean to use -chdir?

In lambda.tf I package some file need to follow this structure, so I cannot go to terraform to init with `./terraform` line

how to resolve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message Terraform returned is suggesting that you use [the `-chdir` option](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/index.html#switching-working-directory-with-chdir), like this:

```
terraform -chdir=./terraform init -input=false -backend=false
terraform -chdir=./terraform validate
```

If you've encountered this while upgrading some existing automation scripts or runbooks for Terraform v0.15 or later, you may find more useful context in [the upgrade guide entry about this new error](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-15.html#commands-accepting-a-configuration-directory-argument).